# Google only indexing alias?

Tags: dns, search-engines

I run our research group website, but don't have direct access to the university DNS server. However, we have two addresses pointing at the same IP - one is the old website and the canonical name is the current one.

```
IP: 128.252.19.134
Old name: lima.wustl.edu
Name name: pappulab.wustl.edu
```

The issue is that any google search returns ONLY the old name (lima.wustl.edu) despite the fact that lima.wust.edu is an alias and pappulab.wustl.edu is the canonical name.

Is there anything I can do to make the webcrawlers use the pappulab.wustl.edu address instead of the lima address? We could just kill lima, but this would break lots of links in various placed.

**Some relevant lookups**

```
nslookup 128.252.19.134
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

134.19.252.128.in-addr.arpa name = pappulab.wustl.edu.
```

---

```
nslookup lima.wustl.edu
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

lima.wustl.edu  canonical name = pappulab.wustl.edu.
Name:   pappulab.wustl.edu
Address: 128.252.19.134
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am not too sure adjusting DNS entries is the best way to handle this. Or would even solve the issue. You do not have an IP address issue, but rather a content indexing & hostname change issue.

I would instead recommend using Apache rewrite rules—via `mod_rewrite`—to do this on `lima.wustl.edu` instead.  This is—of course—assuming that you are running the server on Apache.  If not, someone else should chime in with your server’s specifics.  So here it is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pappulab.wustl.edu$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

What this will basically do—when set for the Apache config of `lima.wustl.edu`—is take any URL connected to `lima.wustl.edu` and send it straight to `pappulab.wustl.edu` but with a `301: Moved Permanently` header status.

So a URL like this:

http://lima.wustl.edu/sometihng/over/here/go.html

Would be sent to:

http://pappulab.wustl.edu/sometihng/over/here/go.html

Links will not break. And the process is pretty seamless to a casual web browser. Meaning no interruption in access that is perceptible to a human. And because the `301` header status is sent, crawlers will take note & update links eventually.  That is always based on the crawler schedule & logic. But I would say in a few weeks or months all of the URLs will properly be reindexed to go to `pappulab.wustl.edu`. To play it safe, leave this redirect up for at least a year.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `robots.txt` file to inform Google not to crawl the old domain.
If the old domain still has a DNS entry and is active, place the following code into your `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If you need the old URLS removed quickly then you can do this in Webmaster Tools.